# Create index with asynchronous population in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, indexing

My Java web-app that launches serveral sql scripts on startup, one of those scripts is a simple index creation on a foreign key.

```
CREATE INDEX "IDX_NAME" on "TABLE" ("IDFK") TABLESPACE "MYTBS"
```

Unfortunately my table has several million rows and the index creation holds the web-app in startup for a few hours (3 in this case).

Is there a way to create the index and populate it asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

use [online](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/indexes003.htm#i1006652) feature:

```
CREATE INDEX "IDX_NAME" on "TABLE" ("IDFK") TABLESPACE "MYTBS" online;
```